How to store user info after login in Next Js which can be accessible from the server pages & actions
`I am using a separate backend with my Next js application. I am using JWT Access token & Refresh token based authentication.
I have created a server action - ApiRequestHandler for handling all the request to my separate backend which I am using on both client & server pages.
Also I have a server action to perform login. Now I can store the userinfo returned in my login method in the client side using context. But how can I store this userinfo in the server side so that I can use on server pages & server actions?
Login Component
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { z } from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Link from "next/link";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { ChevronRight } from "lucide-react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { login } from "@/lib/actions";

const formSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email(),
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(6, { message: "Password must be at least 6 characters long" }),
});

const LoginForm = ({ setCurrentView }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "john@mail.com",
      password: "test123",
    },
  });

  async function onSubmit(values) {
    try {
      values.role = "MANAGER";
      const res = await login(values);
      //   I can store the userinfo to the context
      router.push("/manager");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="rounded-lg bg-white shadow-sm w-10/12 lg:w-10/12 xl:w-6/12 max-w-[400px] border">
      <div className="p-6">
        <div className="mb-6 text-primary font-semibold text-xl">
          Evento Business
        </div>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-3">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="email"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Please enter your email to continue</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input placeholder="Type your email here..." {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="password"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Please enter the password</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="Type your password here..."
                      {...field}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <Button type="submit" className="w-full">
              Login
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Form>
        <div className="mt-4 text-center text-sm">
          Don&apos;t have an account?{" "}
          <Link href="#" className="underline">
            Create now!
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="border-t h-16 flex items-center relative mt-12 p-6">
        <div className="absolute -top-3 bg-white left-4 px-2 font-medium">
          Or sign in as
        </div>

        <Button
          onClick={() => setCurrentView("user")}
          variant="ghost"
          className="hover:bg-inherit pl-0"
        >
          User
          <ChevronRight className="ml-2" />
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;

**ApiRequestHandler.js (Basically a server action) - **
"use server";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { logout } from "./actions";

const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_API_BASE_URL;

const ApiRequestHandler = async (
  url,
  method = "get",
  data = null,
  headers = {},
  retryCount = 1
) => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  let authorizationHeader = {};
  if (cookieStore.has("accessToken")) {
    const accessToken = cookieStore.get("accessToken").value;
    authorizationHeader = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
  }

  const response = await fetch(`${baseURL + url}`, {
    method,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      ...headers,
      ...authorizationHeader,
    },
    body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    if (response.status === 401 && retryCount > 0) {
      const refreshResponse = await refreshToken();
      if (refreshResponse.ok) {
        // Retry the original request with reduced retry count
        return ApiRequestHandler(url, method, data, headers, retryCount - 1);
      } else {
        // Token refresh failed, handle accordingly
        throw new Error("Token refresh failed");
      }
    }
    // Handle other error responses
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
  }
  return response.json();
};

const refreshToken = async () => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  if (cookieStore.has("refreshToken")) {
    const refreshToken = cookieStore.get("refreshToken").value;

    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/auth/refresh`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ refreshToken }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      cookieStore.set("accessToken", jsonResponse.data.accessToken, {
        secure: true,
        // Add other necessary cookie attributes (HttpOnly, SameSite, etc.)
      });
      cookieStore.set("refreshToken", jsonResponse.data.refreshToken, {
        secure: true,
        // Add other necessary cookie attributes (HttpOnly, SameSite, etc.)
      });
    }
    return response;
  } else {
    logout();
  }
};

export default ApiRequestHandler;

**
Other Actions -**
"use server";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import ApiRequestHandler from "./apiRequestHandler";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export const login = async (values) => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  try {
    const res = await ApiRequestHandler("/auth/login", "post", values);
    // res is returning the tokens & userinfo & I want to save this userinfo in the server side
    cookieStore.set("accessToken", res.data.accessToken);
    cookieStore.set("refreshToken", res.data.refreshToken);
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};

export const logout = () => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  cookieStore.delete("accessToken");
  cookieStore.delete("refreshToken");
  redirect("/login");
};



You're using two back ends? State on the server is usually stored in a database of some kind.

I am using a separate express js backend & trying to use next js server as proxy. I am making all the request to my express backend using the next js server action- ApiRequestHandler
